# Synchronize Parse Online Database and Local Data store

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud, local-storage

I am working on project in which I am using Parse online database. Now I am facing issue with syncing between local database and Parse online database.
My problem is like that I have two mobiles having application installed in it. Both mobile application should be remain synced with online Parse. Now suppose I am doing any CRUD(Create, Read,Update and Delete) event in first mobile and it will be saved into its local database. So it will be saved on online Parse also. But now issue is I didn't see any effect of CRUD, which has been done in first mobile, in second mobile. This happens because I am retrieving all data from local data store not from online Parse.

1) How can I sync local data store of two mobile phones?
2) Can you please suggest me other method if above my method looks a complex one?

Any help in this case would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kirtikant

Comment: Did you find an answer?